# Open the Excel VBA hidden sheet using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, vba

Currently trying to update few cells in the Excel VBA hidden sheet using Python but the python code not able to identify the Excel VBA hidden sheet.

Please see below the python code and error details:

- Python code:

[image]

- Error

[image]

Please help with the python code to update cells in VBA hidden sheet.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case that the Worksheet 'Admin' has the ''''xlSheetVeryHidden'''' (=2) state. Change it to ''''xlSheetHidden'''' like this ''''wb.Worksheets('Admin').Visible = 1''''. Then you can access it.